# git rebase - difference between rebasing against develop and origin/develop?

Tags: git, rebase

This is odd. There's apparently some difference between rebasing against my local `develop` branch, and the remote `develop` branch. Here are some details:

So let's say I have a feature branch, `feat`, which I've been rebasing from time to time:

```
git pull --rebase origin develop
```

This is working fine. But now I'm done and ready to squash my commits and I noticed a big difference between:

```
git rebase -i origin develop
```

and

```
git rebase -i develop
```

The former brings up my editor with a *HUGE* list of commits from `develop`, none of them are my changes on `feat`. It also switches me to the `develop` branch. The latter brings up my editor with just my commits on `feat` and does not switch me to my local `develop` branch.

Is `git rebase -i origin develop` actually switching me to my local `develop` and then rebasing against the remote? Am I supposed to `git checkout develop; git pull` first, then `git checkout feat; git rebase -i develop`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git rebase -i origin develop
```

is not the right syntax to use for `rebase`.

```bash
git rebase -i develop
# or this, for the remote-tracking branch
git rebase -i origin/develop
```

are the correct syntaxes.

The [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `git rebase`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) says that this is the general syntax (omitting some options for clarity):

```
git rebase [-i] [<upstream>] [<branch>]
```

where `<upstream>` is a branch:

> ```
> <upstream>
> ```
>
> Upstream branch to compare against. May be any valid commit, not just an existing branch name. Defaults to the configured upstream for the current branch.

When you use `git rebase -i origin develop`, `origin` is the name of your remote, not a branch. If you wanted to rebase against `origin/develop`, you need to use the path separator `/`:

```
git rebase -i origin/develop
```

As for your question:

> Is `git rebase -i origin develop` actually switching me to my local develop and then rebasing against the remote?

It might be switching to your local `develop`, but since the syntax isn't even valid, I'm not 100% sure. The reason I say maybe is because the behavior of `rebase` when you pass a valid upstream branch and another branch is to checkout the second branch before rebasing against the first:

> If `<branch>` is specified, `git rebase` will perform an automatic `git checkout <branch>` before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on the current branch.

Finally, `git rebase -i develop` and `git rebase -i origin/develop` ***could be different*** if your local `develop` isn't update-to-date with your remote-tracking branch `origin/develop`, like if you `git fetch` and never merge updates into your local `develop`.

Comment: I just slapped myself in the forehead. Mentally. The "remote branch" vs "remote/branch" syntax always throws me off. I kinda wish they had stuck with one format across the board. Thank you!

Comment: For typical everyday Git use, maybe it will help to think of it this way. When you do network operations with a remote (e.g. `push`, `push`, `fetch`), you need to specify the remote to talk to, thus `remote branch`, or if the remote has namespaced branches, even `remote namespace/branch`. If you're not talking with a remote, you need the reference (i.e. branch) path. Remember, `remote/branch` is shorthand for the path `refs/remotes/remote/branch`, which is under your repo's `.git` directory. When you just say `branch`, that's shorthand for `refs/heads/branch` in the same `.git` directory.